# How to get patterns from repeated multiple lines files

Tags: python, parsing, text, readlines

I try to make Dataframe from text file. I'm using code that i found on the Internet but i got little stuck and i dont know how to move forward.

> PokerStars Hand #135139509095:  Hold'em No Limit ($0.25/$0.50 USD) - 2015/05/13 2:26:41 ET
>
> Table 'Castafiore II' 6-max Seat #2 is the button
>
> Seat 1: Mastiksou855 ($50 in chips)
>
> Seat 2: tiagosydney ($67.98 in chips)
>
> Seat 3: parisvii1986 ($49.94 in chips)
>
> Seat 4: Johnii141 ($50 in chips)
>
> Seat 5: DavidRandis ($36.59 in chips)
>
> Seat 6: malabar357 ($50 in chips)
>
> *** HOLE CARDS ***
>
> DavidRandis: calls $0.50
>
> malabar357: folds
>
> Mastiksou855: folds
>
> tiagosydney: raises $1 to $1.50
>
> parisvii1986: folds
>
> Johnii141: folds
>
> DavidRandis: calls $1
>
> *** FLOP *** [Jd 9c Tc]
>
> *** TURN *** [Jd 9c Tc] [4s]
>
> *** SUMMARY ***
>
> Total pot $3.75 | Rake $0.17
>
> Board [Jd 9c Tc 4s]
>
> Seat 5: DavidRandis collected ($3.58)
>
> PokerStars Hand #135139512060:  Hold'em No Limit ($0.25/$0.50 USD) - 2015/05/13 2:26:52 ET
>
> Table 'Artek II' 6-max Seat #5 is the button
>
> Seat 1: Johnii141 ($50 in chips)
>
> Seat 2: MASSOS17 ($40 in chips)
>
> Seat 4: jayceee16 ($53.21 in chips)
>
> Seat 5: Mastiksou855 ($50 in chips)
>
> Seat 6: malabar357 ($50 in chips)
>
> malabar357: posts small blind $0.25
>
> *** HOLE CARDS ***
>
> *** SUMMARY ***
>
> Total pot $2.75 | Rake $0.12
>
> Board [7h Td Jc]
>
> Seat 1: Johnii141 (big blind) folded before Flop
>
> Seat 2: MASSOS17 collected ($2.63)
>
> Seat 4: jayceee16 folded on the Flop
>
> Seat 5: Mastiksou855 (button) folded before Flop (didn't bet)
>
> Seat 6: malabar357 (small blind) folded before Flop

This is not full poker hand. Just paste here 2 poker hands as example to show you how its look like.
Full five poker hands example is uploaded here: https://ufile.io/y573n

```
def parse_file(line):
    tab1 = []
    with open(filepath,'r') as file:
        line = file.readline()
        while line:
            reg_match = _reglib(line)

            if reg_match.soft:
                soft = reg_match.soft.group()

            if reg_match.hand_id:
                hand_id = reg_match.hand_id.group(1)

            if reg_match.game_type:
                game_type = reg_match.game_type.group()

            if reg_match.sb:
                sb = reg_match.sb.group(1)

            if reg_match.bb:
                bb = reg_match.bb.group(1)

            if reg_match.date:
                date = reg_match.date.group(1)
                hour = reg_match.date.group(2)
                date_type = reg_match.date.group(3)
            line = file.readline()    
            if reg_match.table:
                table = reg_match.table.group(1)

            if reg_match.rake:
                rake = reg_match.rake.group(1)

            dict_of_data ={
                    'Soft' :soft,
                    'Hand_ID': hand_id,
                    'Game_type':game_type,
                    'SB':sb,
                    'BB':bb,
                    'Date':date,
                    'Hour':hour,
                    'Date_type':date_type,
                    'Table':table,
                    'Rake':rake
                    }
            tab1.append(dict_of_data)
            line = file.readline()        

    tab1 = pd.DataFrame(tab1)
    tab1.set_index(['Soft', 'Hand_ID', 'Game_type'], inplace=True)
    tab1 = tab1.groupby(level=tab1.index.names).first()


    return tab1


class _reglib:

    pat_soft = re.compile('Poker\w+')
    pat_hand_id = re.compile(r'#(\d+):')
    pat_game_type = re.compile('Hold\'em\s\w+\s\w+')
    pat_sb = re.compile('\$(\d+\.?\d+)/')
    pat_bb = re.compile('/\$(\d+\.?\d+)\s\w+')
    pat_date = re.compile('(\d+/\d+/\d+)\s(\d+:\d+:\d+)\s(C?ET)')
    pat_table = re.compile('Table\s\'(\w+...)\'')
    pat_seat = re.compile('(Seat\s\d):\s(\w+)\s\(\$')
    pat_rake = re.compile('Rake\s\$(...)')

    def __init__(self, line):
        # check whether line has a positive match with all of the regular expressions
        self.soft = self.pat_soft.search(line)
        self.hand_id = self.pat_hand_id.search(line)
        self.game_type = self.pat_game_type.search(line)
        self.sb = self.pat_sb.search(line)
        self.bb = self.pat_bb.search(line)
        self.date = self.pat_date.search(line)
        self.table = self.pat_table.search(line)
        self.seat = self.pat_seat.search(line)
        self.rake = self.pat_rake.search(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepath = 'test.txt'
    tab1 = parse_file(filepath)
    print(tab1)
```

So the problem starts when i search for patterns in second line and so on.
This is table information (second line) and rake information (one of last line).

I dont know how to iter over all lines.

If i get the value save it to the dataframe if pattern dont match save None.
For every pokerhand i want one row in dataframe like this: http://prntscr.com/mk2y4t

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `regex` with `pandas`:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data_pd = {'TypeOfRoom': [], 'HandId': [], 'TypeOfGame': [], 'SB': [], 'BB': [], 'Date': [], 'Hour': [], 'TimeZoneAbb': [], 'NoOfPlayers': [], 'Rake': []}
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
result = re.findall('(\w+) Hand #(\d+): (.*) \(.(\d+\.\d+)\/.(\d+\.\d+).*(\d\d\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d).*(\d+:\d+:\d+) (\w+)', data)
rakes = re.findall('Rake \$(.*)', data)

s = re.findall('Seat (\d).*chips', data)
s = [int(x) for x in s]
seats = []
length = 1
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    if s[i+1] < s[i]:
        seats.append(length)
        length = 1
    else:
        length += 1
seats.append(length)

for r, rake, seat in zip(result, rakes, seats):
    data_pd['TypeOfRoom'].append(r[0])
    data_pd['HandId'].append(r[1])
    data_pd['TypeOfGame'].append(r[2])
    data_pd['SB'].append(r[3])
    data_pd['BB'].append(r[4])
    data_pd['Date'].append(r[5])
    data_pd['Hour'].append(r[6])
    data_pd['TimeZoneAbb'].append(r[7])
    data_pd['NoOfPlayers'].append(seat)
    data_pd['Rake'].append(rake)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_pd)
```

You'll get:

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank u so much but i see some problem with these aproach.
First of all nr of players mu be taken from lines Seat 1, Seat 2 etc because table can be 6-max but there may be taken 4 seats or 5 seats for example.
Second of all it not solving how to search other lines to get for example rake from the line under SUMMARY? It different hands number of lines to SUMMARY can be different so we can not use '\n.+' becuase we cannot count how many lines we need to skip.
This is very important to me because i need to make more DataFrames from different lines of text.

Comment: I've added:
1) `Seat` calculation by lines Seat 1, Seat 2 etc.
2) `Rake` parsing.
See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks Alderven for your answer. I'm sure it will help me. I also was coding by myself with little differrent aproach but i have one more problem with information that dont always exist.